# How to programmatically create an InfoPath form from an InfoPath XSN template

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010

I need a solution that creates an InfoPath instance form from an XSN template that exists on a SharePoint server, I am using [this approach](http://blog.halan.se/post/How-to-create-a-new-Form-from-Template-in-a-Form-Library-programmatically.aspx#comment) but this extracts template files on temp directory of server that we may not have write permission to. Is there better solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just change the CAB-library, to one that can extract the template file to memory, as this one,

[Minimum C# code to extract from .CAB archives or InfoPath XSN files, in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533105/minimum-c-sharp-code-to-extract-from-cab-archives-or-infopath-xsn-files-in-mem)

And then call, `myCab.ExtractFile("template.xml", out buffer, out bufferLen);`

the complete code would look something like

```
private byte[] GetXmlForm(SPDocumentLibrary list) {
  byte[] data = null;
  SPFile file = list.ParentWeb.GetFile(list.DocumentTemplateUrl);


  Stream fs = file.OpenBinaryStream();
  try {
    data = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
  } finally {
    fs.Close();
  }

  byte[] buffer;
  int bufferLen;  
  CabExtract cab = new CabExtract(data);
  cab.ExtractFile("template.xml", out buffer, out bufferLen);

  return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Great, I see that your new to the site, do press the up arrow at the left side of the question to indicate that the answer was helpful/useful :)